# Openerp wIth Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, odoo

I had Ubuntu 8.10. I upgrade it to 9.04.
I have Openerp5.0 server/client/web. It worked on 8.10 but not with 9.04.

Now when I try to launch my server using:

```
./openerp-server.py
```

I have this error:

```
ERROR: Import xpath module
ERROR: Try to install the old python-xml package
```

It seems that this version of openerp doesn't work with python2.6.  Can I redirect openerp to use old version of Python?

Answer (score 4):

Google is your friend: http://exploringopenerp.blogspot.com/2009/04/running-openerp-on-ubuntu-904.html

Answer (score 3):

please upgrade your openerp version to 5.0.6, and install python-lxml

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the conf file so that it runs with python2.5 explicitly.